# Find Specifc word with number from a string

Tags: php, preg-match, strpos

I want to get a specific word with number from a string for example

```
ABC312 is the string I want to filter...
```

or

```
ABC 312 is the string I want to filter...
```

Fromt eh above string I want to get "ABC" with following "312" (In the above string ABC will always remain same, it can be case-insensitive but the number will change...) it can be ABC143, ABC001, ABC311, ABC145 etc..

Comment: Will it always be the first word (or two) in the string?

Comment: it can be anywhere in the string actually...

Comment: Bob's your uncle [`~\bABC\s*\d+~i`](http://regex101.com/r/xH5wL6)

Comment: So what are the specific criteria you are trying to match?  That `ABC` part will be some variable string? Does the only need to be zero or one space between string and following number?  Does following number have some specific number of digits? It would help if you could show your current code attempts.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match( '/ABC\s*[0-9]+/' );
```